# How to assign two variables to the same bool?

Tags: python, object, pointers, variables

I am using Python 3.10

```
a = False
b = a
b = not b #or b = True
print(a) # Returns False
```

I would like it to give me True. (Like how it works with lists/other objects)

An terrible solution to this would be (or creating a new object just to hold a bool):

```
a = [False]
b = a
b.clear()
b.append(True)
print(a[0])  # Returns True
```

Looking for an elegant solution to this problem.

Edit: I need this because I am working with multiple threads sharing the same memory space. I need to know when the variable has been changed in the other thread

Comment: Replace `clear` and `append` with `b[0] = 1`, but there's not much else you can do. `a` and `b` are two names referring to the same object; your second approach works because you aren't reassigning either name to a new value, but mutating the existing value in place.

Comment: Lists work the same way; if you can mutate the list in-place, the change is visible in both names, but something like `a = [1,2]; b = a; b = [3,4]` leaves `a` unchanged as well.

Comment: You said you're looking for a solution to this "problem", but you neglected to mention why this is a problem in the first place. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @chepner Yes I realise that. I guess I was expecting either a pointer solution or a `b.opposite()', or something along those lines. If that isn't possible, I will have to use my hacky solution.

Comment: Paul M raises a good point, though: why do you *need* two separate variables that alias each other like this?

Comment: @PaulM. I have a bool variable being changed in another thread. So I need something like this. I could use a list with one variable, but I assumed there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Madh Maybe you're looking for [Event Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects)?

Comment: @PaulM. I have looked into it. I went through it at the start of my project. Basically, its not an Event. One thread is updating variables based on user inputs. And the other needs to access the variables. And I am managing all the other variables using lists/objects. Just felt it was inelegant to have a list with one object (and that too a bool)